# How to make a method run in the "background" (threading?)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, multithreading

I currently have some code that cycles through a text file looking for a specific phrase. However, when this method runs, the whole application locks up. I assume because it's looping, which is what I want.

I would like this to happen in the background, so normal methods and user interaction with the application can still be done.

How can this be done/improved?

```
private void CheckLog()
{   
    while (true)
    {
        // lets get a break
        Thread.Sleep(5000); 

        if (!File.Exists("Command.bat"))
        {
            continue;
        }

        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText("Command.bat"))
        {
            string s = "";

            while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (s.Contains("mp4:production/"))
                {
                    // output it
                    MessageBox.Show(s);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: YABQ: yet another backgroundworker question.

Comment: [Here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/create-asynchronous-method/) is an article with lots of information on asynchronous calls.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multi-threading mechanisms to run some lengthy operations from winforms code and communication with GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457304/multi-threading-mechanisms-to-run-some-lengthy-operations-from-winforms-code-and)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
class Foo {
    private Thread thread;
    private void CheckLog() {...}
    private void StartObserving() {
        thread = new Thread(this.CheckLog);
        thread.Start();
    }
}
```

or the backgroundworker component from the palette.